# Hover is not working on a class

Tags: css

```
HTML
<body>
  <div class="show">
    <span>hover here</span>
  </div>
  <div class="hide">
    <span>it works</span>
  </div>
</body>


CSS
.hide{
background-color:grey;
visibility:hidden;
     }
.show:hover .hide{
visibility:visible;
     }
```

The hover function is not working for the class hide.Why?
And how can I fix this?? https://jsfiddle.net/jet9gbwe/

Comment: `.show:hover + .hide` instead

Answer (score 2):

You need an adjacent sibling selector `+`

```
.show:hover + .hide{
    visibility:visible;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try simply adding a `+` between your :hover and target class.

```
.hide{
    background-color:grey;
    visibility:hidden;
}
.show:hover + .hide{
    visibility:visible;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1x4rd7je/